# Python arrays: why is the output 3

Tags: python, arrays

Can someone explain me why the output of the variable a is 3?

```
a = [4,3,1][1]
```

(Output) 3

Comment: 3 is the element at index 1 in the list [4,3,1]

Comment: You are defining an array, and selecting the second element which is index 1, since it starts from 0.

Comment: @Ahmet That's a `list`.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa tomato tomato. You are technically correct but i feel the terms are interchangeable in python, unless numpy etc is the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining an array `[4, 3, 1]`. By writing `[1]` you are selecting the second element of this array (the arrays in python start from 0). So `a` equals to the second element of array - 3. If you write [0] or [2] you get 4 or 1 accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the first (array count starts at 0) element of your array [4, 3, 1], which is 3.

Answer (score 1):

To be easier to understand, think of that line of code as split into two:

```
list = [4,3,1]
a = list[1]
```

You are indexing the 1st position (indexing starts at 0), which is the value 3 in the list you defined.